# How to use Collect Values with Cell Statistics in iterative model in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, viewshed

I'm trying to run multiple viewsheds in ArcGIS 10, reclassify these rasters and finally add them together. This is for a wind farm project where we need to repeat multiple viewsheds from various turbines and therefore the process lends itself particularly well to Modelbuilder.

My problem is that I am unable to get the Collect Values and Cell Statistics tools to work together to locate the reclassified rasters and add them together (see lower part of my model below):

[image: Cumulative viewshed]

There are a few threads dotted around that have been useful ([here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/66535-Using-iterative-Model-Builder-outputs-in-raster-calculator) and [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000005000000)), but none have show their final models.

Can anyone show me how to correctly use the Collect Values tool to point to the reclassified rasters and use the Cell Statistics tool to sum these up?

**Update with working model**

Here is the revised (working) model for cumulative viewsheds. The user simple needs to point the model to a list of turbine point files for it to run. Thanks all.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your model with the iterator to go viewshed > reclassify > collect values. This will create a list of grids. Expose the collects value as a parameter. This whole model is then a submodel to another model where you connect the output (your collect values) to the cell stats tool.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, for some reason I was not allowed to connect the reclassify and collect values tools but have now managed to by setting up the model again from scratch. I still am unable to 'expose the collects value as a parameter' but this isn't a deal breaker for now. I've updated my original question with the working model. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From your model it looks like you have not added a Connection from the output of Reclassify to your Collect Values tool.  There is an **[example diagram](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Examples_of_using_Model_Only_tools_in_ModelBuilder/00400000001m000000/GUID-9F197B15-27F6-46EA-BAC5-7A722C5A3C4E/)** illustrating this in the online help.

Comment: Thanks for the link. As per my response to Hornbydd above, I've now solved this problem using both of your resources. See revised model above. Thanks!